# Displaying a to a List from a private void method

Tags: c#, winforms

I just started developing in Winforms and I'm developing a simple recipe app that allows the user to create a recipe, submit all the details about the recipe, those details will be passed back to a ListBox on the Main form so the user can access that recipe again later. My problem is right now is when I'm finished setting up the recipe to submit, I don't know how to transfer the information back to the ListBox to be stored. I know this has to be a simple answer and I appreciate the help.

Main form code:

```
public partial class Main : Form
{
    // Creat the recipeList here and make it public
    public static List<Recipe> recipeList = new List<Recipe>();

    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void newRecipeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // When the new recipe button is clicked, create a new AddNewRecipeForm object that passed the recipeList.
        var newForm = new AddNewRecipeForm(recipeList);
        newForm.Show();
    }

    private void recipeListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // List the New Recipe in the listbox.           
    }
}
```

Second form code:

```
public partial class AddNewRecipeForm : Form
{
    // Create a private recipeList
    private List<Recipe> recipeList = new List<Recipe>();

    // Once AddNewRecipe is create, it uses the recipeList as the parameters.
    public AddNewRecipeForm(List<Recipe> recipeList)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void submitRecipeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Create a newRecipe object.
        Recipe newRecipe = new Recipe();

        // Add each entry made in the textboxes to newRecipe object.
        newRecipe.Name = nameTextBox.Text;
        newRecipe.Time = Convert.ToInt32(timeTextBox.Text);
        newRecipe.Servings = Convert.ToInt32(servingsTextBox.Text);
        newRecipe.Directions = directionsTextBox.Text;
        newRecipe.Ingredients = ingredientsTextBox.Text;

        // Add the newRecipe object to the recipeList.
        recipeList.Add(newRecipe);

        // Close the window.
        this.Close();
    }                
}
```

Comment: in `AddNewRecipeForm` you can add a public getter for `recipeList`, then in `Main` just use something like `recipeList = newForm.GetRecipeList();`

Comment: Also you pass in `recipeList` to `AddNewRecipeForm` but don't assign it to your private variable. If you do end up doing that, you'll need to change the param name in the AddNewRecipeForm constructor or change your private variable name to `_recipeList` which is sort of convention these days

Answer (score 0):

Use a  [BindingList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of a list. Whenever you add items to it, it will notify your lisbox and the listbox will update itself. Make sure you import `using System.ComponentModel;`:

```
private BindingList<Recipe> recipeList = new BindingList<Recipe>();
```

Set the `DataSource` of the `ListBox` to the recipeList like this:

```
this.recipeListBox.DataSource = items;
// Instruct the listbox to display the Name or any property
this.recipeListBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
// Optionally instruct the listbox that the ValueMember is Name
// If you use SelectedValue, it will return the value from this property
this.recipeListBox.ValueMember = "Name";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            Main Form:                
                  public partial class Main : Form
                {
                    // Creat the recipeList here and make it public
                    public List<Recipe> recipeList = new List<Recipe>();

                    public Main()
                    {
                        InitializeComponent();
                    }

                    private void newRecipeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                    {
                        // When the new recipe button is clicked, create a new AddNewRecipeForm object that passed the recipeList.
                        var newForm = new AddNewRecipeForm(recipeList);       
                        newForm.Show();
         **recipeList =newForm.ReceiptList;**
    //assign recipeList  values to list box
                    }

                    private void recipeListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
                    {
                        // List the New Recipe in the listbox.           
                    }
                }





Second Form:

public partial class AddNewRecipeForm : Form
{
    // Create a private recipeList
    **private List<Recipe> recipeList = new List<Recipe>();
public List<Recipe> RecipeList
{
 get { return recipeList; }
 set { recipeList = value; }
}**

    // Once AddNewRecipe is create, it uses the recipeList as the parameters.
    public AddNewRecipeForm(List<Recipe> recipeList)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void submitRecipeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Create a newRecipe object.
        Recipe newRecipe = new Recipe();

        // Add each entry made in the textboxes to newRecipe object.
        newRecipe.Name = nameTextBox.Text;
        newRecipe.Time = Convert.ToInt32(timeTextBox.Text);
        newRecipe.Servings = Convert.ToInt32(servingsTextBox.Text);
        newRecipe.Directions = directionsTextBox.Text;
        newRecipe.Ingredients = ingredientsTextBox.Text;

        // Add the newRecipe object to the recipeList.
        recipeList.Add(newRecipe);

        // Close the window.
        this.Close();
    }                
}
```